# Dropdown select options translation in angular-js for multilingual site

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have set of options to bind to a select box.

Say the array is defined like whose content is to be bind to the dropdown.

```
$scope.options = [
        { City: "en", },
        { City: "nl" },
        ....
        ....
        like so
    ];
```

And the typical code to bind the above options

```
<select ng-model="selectedcity"                 
            ng-options="i.City for i in options">
</select>
```

This works fine.

But I would like to implement language specific options.

So what is the correct way to translate this City values and bind to dropdown.Because I have multilingual site where I would need to show the dropdowns in different languages.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at ngTranslate and this posts

[How to ng-translate inside select box option in angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23568180/how-to-ng-translate-inside-select-box-option-in-angularjs)

[angular-translate ad ng-options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23765622/angular-translate-ad-ng-options)

Basically you are using the translate filter in the options expression like

```
<select ng-model="selectedcity"                 
        ng-options="i.City | translate for i in options">
</select>
```