# Populate ng-option in angular with a list in json (with angular translate)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, ng-options, angular-translate

I have a similar question as these ones :

[How to ng-translate inside select box option in angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23568180/how-to-ng-translate-inside-select-box-option-in-angularjs)

[angular-translate ad ng-options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23765622/angular-translate-ad-ng-options)

But my case is a bit different.
I would like that my ng-option fill up automatically with elements from a list in my json. And I would like to avoid defining these elements in my controller (because otherwise each time an element is added to the list I will need to add them in my controller manually).

Here is the concerned part in my .json :

```
 "availLanguages" : [
   "Deutsch",
   "English",
   "Français"
  ],
```

My controller's instance is called "language". So I've tried the followings :

```
 <select ng-options="language for languages in 'availLanguages' | translate" ng-model="language.selectedLanguage" ng-change="language.changeLanguage()"></select>
```

Thanks,

EDIT: here's the result :

[image]

Each object is a letter from "availLanguages".

Answer (score 0):

You haven't passed the value of ng-model to you scope function. try this. this might help you. console selected language in function.

```
<select ng-options="language in 'availLanguages' | translate" ng-model="language.selectedLanguage" ng-change="language.changeLanguage(language.selectedLanguage)"></select>
```

Comment: Well I've mocked this function so that the testing is easier. For now this function only swap between two set values. but my ng-options doesn't work because my drop down list is empty.

Comment: Provide a plunkr, codepen or jsfiddle and I might be able to help